Unable to import bootstrap in vue 3 properly, how can fix it?
I am trying to achieve bootstrap popover in vue porject. but i get boostrap is not defined.
this is the code I wrote and i get bootstrap is not defined error, i get that error because i am using bootstrap.Popover(). Can you please assist why i cant use bootstrap in eventClick.

//Popover functionality


<template>
  <div>
    <FullCalendar :options="calendarOptions" ref="fullCalendarRef" />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/vue'
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'
import bootstrap from 'bootstrap'

const fullCalendarRef = ref(null)

const calendarOptions = {
  plugins: [dayGridPlugin],
  initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
  events: [
    // your events here
  ],
  eventContent: function(info) {
    const popover = new bootstrap.Popover(info.el, {
      content: info.event.title,
      trigger: 'hover'
    })
  }
}

onMounted(() => {
  fullCalendarRef.value.getApi().render()
})
</script>




Just curious, you need to instantiate bootstrap, no? Like `const popover = new bootstrap().Popover('blah blah blah')

Yes, when i use boostrap().Popover or bootstrap.Popover i get error saying boostrap is not defined.

You must include popper.min.js before bootstrap.js or use bootstrap.bundle.min.js / bootstrap.bundle.js which contains Popper in order for popovers to work! Popovers require the tooltip plugin as a dependency.

import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js'
was it this ? I added it to main.js, should i add it to component aswell?

yes , you should add it to component

this is the order:
import {defineComponent, ref, onMounted} from 'vue'
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/vue3'
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid'
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction'
import { INITIAL_EVENTS, createEventId } from './event-utils'
import bootstrap5Plugin from '@fullcalendar/bootstrap5';
// import 'bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js'
still i get bootstrap is not defined

ok, it seems like removing boostrap resolved but popover is not initializing properly. i will work on it.

First ensure that you have bootstrap css and js included in your project

i have both. looking at the methods called in libraries in bootstrap, we dont have to use bootstrap.Popover() to show popover.

npm install bootstrap jquery

after that  import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js';

if not worked, then  refer https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/

I am using boostrap 5.

import {Popover} from "bootstrap";
by importing in above similar way and Just Adding Poper() method resolved the problem.
